# Losing arrow keys in vim under screen

Tags: command-line, screen, vim

Under certain circumstances I lose the ability to use arrow keys in vim. I just installed 16.04 LTS and I didnot have this problem with earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Using [PAC Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/files/) tabbed SSH client to connect to remote server then I start a `screen` session. PAC Manager seems to have a trouble where I have no scrollback in new `screen` session unless I "reset" the terminal. (keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) so I do the reset.

After the terminal reset now I have scrollback but in vim the arrow keys no longer work (screen "blinks" like `screen` does when it wants to do a bell sound).  Only way to restore arrows is to exit `screen` session.

Best solution would be fix why I need terminal reset to get scrollback working. But I think easier to expect more help to restore missing arrow keys.

PS: terminal type is not solution because I tried changing $TERM with not success and anyway arrow keys work fine in `screen` until I do "terminal reset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to prevent screen handling the scrollback. Add to `.screenrc`

```
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
```

Now local terminal handles scrollback

Answer (score 0):

`screen` switches the terminal emulator to the so-called "alternate screen" mode, in which no scrollback is provided by the terminal emulator. Instead, `screen` offers its own methods (via keyboard) to scroll back.

It is a false assumption from you to run `screen` and be able to use the regular scrollbar at the same time, and even if you make it happen via hacks (such as resetting the terminal emulator, hence leaving the alternate screen), the scrollback contents are sure not what you expect. You should either refrain from using `screen`, or get familiar with the keyboard-based scrolling mechanism it provides.

`screen` and/or `vim` asks the terminal emulator to emit different sequences for keypresses than the default, and Reset even reverts this, so the generated sequences no longer match the expectation.

Comment: Scrollback is provided by the terminal emulator (PAC) and fact is that its exactly what I expect, as I said it worked fine until 16.04. All I want to figure is how to re-enable arrow keys, why they are being seen as different input to screen for odd reason.